# How to use onleft editext for multiple button (Android)

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have three buttons, chatOn button , chatoff button , and chatReallyOff button. when user click on ChatOn Button that time ChatOff button display similar with chat really off button . now i want to use these button on left of edittext i am able to set alignparent left in editext for chatOn button but problem is that how two set alignparent for these three buttons..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOnChat"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btonchat" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOffChat"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btoffchat" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOffChatReally"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btoffchat_really" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
//Want to use this line                  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btSendText|btOffChat|btOffChatReally"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btOnChat"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" 
        android:hint="Type a message..."
        android:background="@drawable/chatboxbackground"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btSendText"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btsend" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: see below i have posted

Comment: how do you want to align these buttons in left ? side by side  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to put your 3 buttons into a new `RelativeLayout`, and then set your edittext `toLeftOf` to the new `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Yes you are write, i did i have did just like following... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed just like this :

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOnChat"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btonchat" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOffChat"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btoffchat" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btOffChatReally"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btoffchat_really" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/form1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btSendText"
   >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/chatboxbackground"
        android:hint="Type a message..."
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btSendText"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btsend" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```